# Apache Virtualhost e Internet Information Services (IIS)

Tags: apache, iis, virtualhost

Estuve haciendo un proyecto en Apache usando WAMPSERVER64 con un Virtual Host y después instale IIS, esto provocó que el Virtualhost deje de funcionar, desinstalé el IIS y aun así me sale la página de IIS, busqué en Internet y no encontré ninguna respuesta clara.

[image: Página por defecto de IIS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posiblemente tengas conflicto de Puertos ya que los dos utiliza 80. trata de cambiar el numero de puerto de apache

[xampp](https://www.jsolucioncreativa.com/cambiar-los-puertos-de-apache-y-mysql-en-xampp-correctamente/)

[WAMP](https://techlandia.com/cambiar-numero-puerto-servidor-apache-wamp-como_41661/)

Comment: si eso lo había hecho antes pero siempre me daba un poco de problemas, al final lo solucione con un punto de restauración del sistema a una semana atras...
sí, lo se, me fui por la solución fácil pero funciono jeje.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda